# EF6 insert of parent and child

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

in EF6 the parent inserted but its child not saved and give error

```
public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
        {

            entity.ObjectState = ObjectState.Added;

            _dbSet.Attach(entity);
            context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
```

but it give error :

A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of  n one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of n the other end

the models looks like

```
public class student 
{
public int Id;
virtual ICollection<Courses> Courseslist ;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your model classes?

Comment: @Noel please check my updated code

Comment: what about your `Courses` class?  Also, if you are using any configuration classes that would help too.

Comment: contains only the Id of public Nullable<int> studentid{ get; set; }

Comment: You are going to need to loop through the child collection and set their state explicitly. https://dzone.com/articles/solving-detached-many-many